# VNC installation

Tags: linux, vnc-viewer

I just downloaded this package VNC-Viewer-6.17.731-Linux-x64-ANY.tar to install the VNC viewer. I want to do the installation manually without using the yum. When I type the `./vncinstall` command to perform the installation it gives me the following:

```
Copying vncviewer to /usr/bin
Copying vncviewer.1 to /usr/share/man/man1/vncviewer.1
```

Does this mean that the vnc was properly installed?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does mean it was installed correctly. You can run it with `vncviewer`. `vncviewer.1` is the `man` page (documentation) for the executable.